# Why i got TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

I was building a website called starwarplanet.

It used react.js to build.

What it use the api is [this website](https://swapi.co/api/planets/)

And i got the error from it is

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
```

I just want to show the planet's `name`,`diameter` and `rotation_period`.

What is the problem in my `app.js` or `card.js`?

in `app.js`:

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import CardList from '../Components/CardList';
import SearchBox from '../Components/SearchBox';
import Scroll from '../Components/Scroll';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component{
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.state={
            planets:[],
            searchfield:''
        }
     }
     componentDidMount() {
        const urls = [
           'https://swapi.co/api/planets/',
           'https://swapi.co/api/planets/?page=2', 
           'https://swapi.co/api/planets/?page=3',
           'https://swapi.co/api/planets/?page=4',
           'https://swapi.co/api/planets/?page=5',
           'https://swapi.co/api/planets/?page=6',
           'https://swapi.co/api/planets/?page=7'
    ]
    
    Promise.all(urls.map(async url => {
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const morePlanets = await response.json();
        var combinedArrayOfPlanets = this.state.planets;
        combinedArrayOfPlanets.push(morePlanets.results);
        
        var sortedArrayOfPlanets = combinedArrayOfPlanets
            .flat()
            .sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name));
        
        this.setState({planets: sortedArrayOfPlanets})
    }))
    .catch(error => 
        console.log('Error during fetching of planets:', error)
    );
}

onSearchChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ searchField: event.target.value })
}
render(){
    const {planets,searchField} = this.state;
    const filteredPlanets = planets.filter(planet=>{
        return planet.name.toLowerCase().includes(
            searchField.toLowerCase())
            ||
            planet.diameter.toLowerCase().includes(
                searchField.toLowerCase())
            ||
            planet.rotation_period.toLowerCase().includes(
                searchField.toLowerCase())
    })
    return !planets.length?
    (
        <div className='tc'>
                    <h1>Loading</h1>:
        </div>
    ):
    (
    <div className='tc'>
        <h1 className='f2'>StarWarPlanet</h1>
        <SearchBox searchChange={this.onSearchChange}/>
        <Scroll>
            <CardList planets = {filteredPlanets}/>
        </Scroll>
    </div>
    );
   }
  }

 export default (App);
```

in `Card.js`:

```
import React from 'react';

const Card = ({name,diameter,rotation_period}) =>{
    return(
       <div className="bg-light-green dib br3 pa3 ma2 grow bw2 shadow-5">
            <div>
                <h2>{name}</h2>
                <p>{diameter}</p>
                <p>{rotation_period}</p>
            </div>
       </div>
    );
   }

   export default Card;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error arises when you want to perform operation on something that does not exists. You seem to be running `toLowerCase` on some property that is not present in its parent. Check the error log for the exact line number. You will get to know which non-existing property you are trying to access.

It should be one of these:

```
planet.name.toLowerCase()
planet.diameter.toLowerCase()
planet.rotation_period.toLowerCase()
```

So check to ensure planet has all 3 properties: `name`, `diameter` and `rotation_period`. If yes, make sure you used correct spelling.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.Correct spelling is right. I miss searchfied this kind of word and it should be searchField

Comment: @Jacky Cheers, it happens.

Answer (score 1):

This might be due to data is not in perfect string format. Try to add `.toString()` then try adding `.toLowerCase()`

Comment: Based on the error, the error being throw because of `undefined.toLowerCase()` which I don't think add `.toString()` can possibly solve the problem since we can't apply `toString()` on `undefined` variable as well?

Answer (score 1):

Your component is trying to render before the data is finished fetching. You have the check in your code, but you need to move it before you do any processing of the data:

```
render() {
    const {planets,searchField} = this.state;

    if (!planets.length) {
        return <div className='tc'><h1>Loading</h1></div>;
    }

    const filteredPlanets = planets.filter(planet=>{
        return planet.name.toLowerCase().includes(
            searchField.toLowerCase())
            ||
            planet.diameter.toLowerCase().includes(
                searchField.toLowerCase())
            ||
            planet.rotation_period.toLowerCase().includes(
                searchField.toLowerCase())
    })
    return (
        <div className='tc'>
            <h1 className='f2'>StarWarPlanet</h1>
            <SearchBox searchChange={this.onSearchChange}/>
            <Scroll>
                <CardList planets = {filteredPlanets}/>
            </Scroll>
        </div>
    );
}
```