# Serverless Error TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless, aws-serverless, aws-java-sdk

I tried to deploy something like [this example](https://www.serverless.com/blog/how-to-create-a-rest-api-in-java-using-dynamodb-and-serverless/) from [serverless](https://www.serverless.com/). Building my `serverless.yml`, I run into this error, of which I don't find a handle to deal with:

```yaml
service: products-api

package:
  artifact: target\products-api-dev.jar
  #artifact: target\${self:service}-${self:provider.stage}.jar #cool alternative :)

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: java8

#Copy-pasted
resources:
  Resources:
    productsTable:
      Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
      Properties:
        TableName: products_table
        AttributeDefinitions:
          - AttributeName: id
            AttributeType: S
          - AttributeName: name
            AttributeType: S
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: id
            KeyType: HASH
          - AttributeName: name
            KeyType: RANGE
        ProvisionedThroughput:
          ReadCapacityUnits: 1
          WriteCapacityUnits: 1

functions:
  listProducts:
    handler: com.serverless.ListProductsHandler
    events:
      - http:
          path: /products
          method: get
  getProduct:
    handler: com.serverless.GetProductHandler
    events:
      - http:
          path: /products/{id}
          method: get
  createProduct:
    handler: com.serverless.CreateProductHandler
    events:
      - http:
          path: /products
          method: post
  deleteProduct:
    handler: com.serverless.DeleteProductHandler
    events:
      - http:
          path: /products/{id}
```

The error I get is this - not having a reference to a mistake in my own code makes difficult to spot where I went wrong.
I looked into many Q/A including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55292269/why-i-got-typeerror-cannot-read-property-tolowercase-of-undefined) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42542137/typescript-cannot-read-property-tolowercase-of-undefined), but it seems to be more of a javascript and typescript problem there, not serverless as here.

```
 Type Error ----------------------------------------------

  TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
      at AwsCompileApigEvents.getHttpMethod (C:\snapshot\serverless\lib\plugins\aws\package\compile\events\apiGateway\lib\validate.js:195:24)
      at C:\snapshot\serverless\lib\plugins\aws\package\compile\events\apiGateway\lib\validate.js:50:30
      at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
      at C:\snapshot\serverless\lib\plugins\aws\package\compile\events\apiGateway\lib\validate.js:45:37
      at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
      at AwsCompileApigEvents.validate (C:\snapshot\serverless\lib\plugins\aws\package\compile\events\apiGateway\lib\validate.js:44:55)
      at Object.package:compileEvents [as hook] (C:\snapshot\serverless\lib\plugins\aws\package\compile\events\apiGateway\index.js:318:31)
      at PluginManager.invoke (C:\snapshot\serverless\lib\classes\PluginManager.js:579:20)
      at async PluginManager.spawn (C:\snapshot\serverless\lib\classes\PluginManager.js:601:5)
      at async Object.before:deploy:deploy [as hook] (C:\snapshot\serverless\lib\plugins\deploy.js:60:11)
      at async PluginManager.invoke (C:\snapshot\serverless\lib\classes\PluginManager.js:579:9)
      at async PluginManager.run (C:\snapshot\serverless\lib\classes\PluginManager.js:639:7)
      at async Serverless.run (C:\snapshot\serverless\lib\Serverless.js:452:5)
      at async C:\snapshot\serverless\scripts\serverless.js:751:9
     For debugging logs, run again after setting the "SLS_DEBUG=*" environment variable.
```

Answer (score 0):

[andymac4182](https://github.com/andymac4182) has the Idea for [the solution for your problem](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/2136#issuecomment-247201000) and it is actually pretty easy. You have to define a method for each http element, and for the last one, this is missing: `method: post`

Updated:

```yaml
  deleteProduct:
    handler: com.serverless.DeleteProductHandler
    events:
      - http:
          path: /products/{id}
          method: post
```

Answer (score 0):

Serverless is a javascript project, which is why you're seeing a javascript error.

It appears one of your functions is an HTTP endpoint, but lacks any methods. That seems to be the cause of the error.

Try adding `method: DELETE` to your endpoint:

```
  deleteProduct:
    handler: com.serverless.DeleteProductHandler
    events:
      - http:
          path: /products/{id}
          method: DELETE
```